# Elasticsearch node is failing to get started

Tags: elasticsearch

I was using ES 5.4.3 version and it was running smoothly with corresponding Kibana and logstash, until I found the Elasticsearch node is failing to start and showing below error message now.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xwe7.png)

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have multiple nodes ? are they same version ?

Comment: I used the default configuration to setup Elasticsearch in my windows system. So I guess, it has a single node.